# How to find a document by presence of nested field?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, object, nosql

I have documents like this:

```
"_id" : 16,
"cup" : "DSLB--1902/2019",
"nombre" : "Rehabilitación de drenaje sanitario en zona sur",
"tipo" : "DRENAJE SANITARIO",
"subtipo" : "LÍNEA DE BOMBEOS",
"descripcion" : "Prueba 1000",
"estatus" : "1",
"capitulos" : {
    "Suministro e instalación" : {
        "PRELIMINARES" : [ 
            {
                "especificacion" : "A-04",
                "partida" : "1.4.4",
                "concepto" : "TRAMITE Y PERMISOS PARA LA CONSTRUCCION DE LA OBRA COMO SON OCUPACIÒN, CRUCES, INSTALACIONES MARGINALES, ROTURA Y REPOSICIÒN DE LA VÌA PÙBLICA ANTE DEPENDENCIAS CORRESPONDIENTES. COMO SON DEPENDENCIAS FEDERALES, ESTATALES, MUNICIPALES Y PRIVADAS, INCLUYE CALCULOS, PLANOS LEVANTAMIENTOS ESPECIFICOS DEL PERMISO, COPIAS REQUERIDAS.",
                "conceptov" : "MUNICIPALES",
                "cantidad" : "123",
                "unidad" : "UN."
            }, 
            {
                "especificacion" : "A-02",
                "partida" : "1.2.5",
                "concepto" : "LOCALIZACIÓN Y/O REPOSICIÓN DE SERVICIOS PÚBLICOS EXISTENTES, COMO SON INSTALACIONES SUBTERRÁNEAS Y AÉREAS DE LAS COMPAÑÍAS DE SERVICIOS PÚBLICOS, QUE PUEDAN INTERFERIR CON EL DESARROLLO DE LOS TRABAJOS ENCOMENDADOS AL CONTRATISTA, COMO SON:",
                "conceptov" : "GAS",
                "cantidad" : "23",
                "unidad" : "UN."
            }
        ]
    }
},
"updated_at" : ISODate("2019-02-25T16:12:38.000-06:00"),
"created_at" : ISODate("2019-02-19T10:51:37.000-06:00")
```

Where "capitulos" can have more children with another names (not only "Suministros e instalación"), but all in the same format. In this case, I'm looking for all documents that have the object "PRELIMINARES".  Is there a way to get this?

For the plus, if having this, update the name of the searched object.

Comment: What do you mean by "update the name of the searched object?" Are you trying to rename that field? The rename update operator should help there -- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/

Comment: @willis I know it, but first I need to solve the first problem. And for this, I'm not sure if the rename function could work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! It sounds like you care whether or not a key exists, so you'll want to use the [`$exist` query operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/). So, a query like `{"capitulos.Suministro e instalación.PRELIMINARES": {$exists: true}}` should find your document.

You could also use the [`$type` query operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) if you wanted to check whether `PRELIMINARES` is actually an object.

Comment: The problem here is that the name of the second object (in this case "Suministro e instalación") varies, so this will don't work. I need a query where I can "skip" the second object and find if "capitulos" have the object I'm looking for.

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case, I think your only option might be the [`$where` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) and running javascript. It's ugly and slow, but something like `db.test.find({$where: "Object.keys(this).some((k) => Object.keys(this[k]).includes('b'))"})` will find documents like `{"a" : { "b" : 1 }}`

Comment: How can I use your query in this example? I tried this: `db.proyectos.find({$where: "Object.keys(this).PRELIMINARES((k) => Object.keys(this[k]).includes('PRELIMINARES'))"})` but shows `"errmsg" : "TypeError: Object.keys(...).PRELIMINARES is not a function :\n@:1:22\n",
 "code" : 139,`

Comment: `Object.keys(this.capitulos).some((k) => this.[k] && this[k].PRELIMINARES)`